# Recording the data from SQL Server's Activity Monitor

Tags: sql-server, performance

I'm looking to record that data that appears in SQL Server's "Activity Monitoring" panel. Activity Monitor provides a nice overview of what's happening on the database at the current instance, so it would be good to be able record this data over a few hours to be able analyze it in more detail.

I'm particularity interested in the contents of the "Recent Expensive Queries" panel. I understand this data comes from sys.dm_exec_requests and sys.dm_exec_query_stats, so it wouldn't be too difficult to write a small script to dump the contents of these to a file periodically, but I was wondering if something already existed to do that.

We're using: SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Profiler to get all the queries and stored procedures used in that screen. But, I use this:

```
SELECT TOP 10
    qs.execution_count,
    qs.total_logical_reads, qs.last_logical_reads,
    qs.total_logical_writes, qs.last_logical_writes,
    qs.total_worker_time, 
    qs.last_worker_time,
    qs.total_elapsed_time/1000000 total_elapsed_time_in_S,
    qs.last_elapsed_time/1000000 last_elapsed_time_in_S,
    qs.last_execution_time,
    SUBSTRING(qt.TEXT, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
    ((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
        WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.TEXT)
        ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
        END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2)+1) Query
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) qt
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) qp
ORDER BY qs.{What to sort on} DESC
```